# Dashing issue in Graphics

Tags: graphics3d, pdf-format, graphics

I have plotted a 3D image using `Graphics3D` and I have included a `Dashing` option. If I save the image as a png file (left image) then there is no problem but when I save it as pdf/eps (right image) then there seems to be a problem. I have seen some threads discussing this problem and have applied their solutions but none works, e.g. using `CapForm`, `AbsoluteDashing`, etc. I was thinking maybe it has to do with my Mathematica version 12.3 and currently running on Windows 10 Home version 20H2, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
r = 0.5;
rbelow = 0.49;
dbelow = {0, 0, -1.5};
rabove = 0.49;
dabove = {0, 0, 1.5};
HemisphereBelow = ParametricPlot3D[rbelow {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]} + dbelow, {u, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {v, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, PlotPoints -> {25, 25}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
HemisphereAbove = ParametricPlot3D[rabove {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]} + dabove, {u, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {v, \[Pi]/2, 3 \[Pi]/2}, PlotPoints -> {25, 25}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
InnerCylinder = ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[u], r Sin[u], z}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {z, -1.49, 1.49}, PlotPoints -> 25, PlotStyle -> Green, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
QuarterCircleBelow = RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[0.5^2 - (r - 1)^2] - 1.5, {r, 0.5, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
QuarterCircleAbove = RevolutionPlot3D[-Sqrt[0.5^2 - (r - 1)^2] + 1.5, {r, 0.5, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
circle3D[centre_ : {0, 0, 0}, radius_ : 1, normal_ : {0, 0, 1}, angle_ : {0, 2 Pi}] := Composition[Line, Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre], #] &, Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &, #] &, Append[DeleteDuplicates[Most@#], Last@#] &, Level[#, {-2}] &, MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &, DiscretizeRegion, If][First@Differences@angle >= 2 Pi, Circle[Most@centre, radius], Circle[Most@centre, radius, angle]]
DiskLowerHorizon = ParametricPlot3D[{rdisk Sin[Pi/2] Cos[\[Phi]], rdisk Sin[Pi/2] Sin[\[Phi]], rdisk Cos[Pi/2] - 0.1}, {rdisk, 0, 1}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Gray, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
DiskUpperHorizon = ParametricPlot3D[{rdisk Sin[Pi/2] Cos[\[Phi]], rdisk Sin[Pi/2] Sin[\[Phi]], rdisk Cos[Pi/2] + 0.1}, {rdisk, 0, 1}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> Gray, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.03, Black], Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1.5}, {0, 0, 1.5}}, 1]}, {Opacity[0.3, Green], InnerCylinder}, {Opacity[0.5, Blue], HemisphereBelow}, {Opacity[0.5, Blue], HemisphereAbove}, {Opacity[0.4, Red], QuarterCircleBelow}, {Opacity[0.4, Red], QuarterCircleAbove}, {Black, Thickness[0.005], circle3D[{0, 0, -1}, 1]}, {Black, Thickness[0.005], circle3D[{0, 0, 1}, 1]}, {CapForm["Butt"], Purple, Dashing[{0.03, 0.05}], Thickness[0.008], circle3D[{0, 0, -0.1}, 0.5]}, {CapForm["Butt"], Purple, Dashing[{0.03, 0.05}], Thickness[0.008], circle3D[{0, 0, 0.1}, 0.5]}, {Opacity[0.3], DiskLowerHorizon}, {Opacity[0.3], DiskUpperHorizon}, {CapForm["Butt"], Purple, Dashing[{0.03, 0.05}], Thickness[0.008], circle3D[{0, 0, -0.1}, 1]}, {CapForm["Butt"], Purple, Dashing[{0.03, 0.05}], Thickness[0.008], circle3D[{0, 0, 0.1}, 1]}, {Black, Thickness[0.005], Line[{{0, 0, -1.5}, {0, 0, 1.5}}]}, {Black, PointSize[Large], Point[{{0, 0, -0.10}, {0, 0, 0.10}}]}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: `Export["test.pdf", Rasterize[%, RasterSize -> 800]]`

Comment: Mathemania, have you tried updating to the latest version of Mathematica, 12.3.1?

Comment: @CATrevillian Not really, but I will soon try. However, the method of cvgmt worked!